# Changed Merkle Root and Genesis Hash - Not Compiling

Tags: altcoin

I am kindly asking the expert programmers of this wonderful forum to enlighten me on why the updated QT I have created, does not properly open when running ./stonecoin-qt , but rather dumps core and shows the incorrect genesis block for the -testnet flag

after updating all the parameters in the github repo below

> https://github.com/advantage-project/stonedfork
>
> ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make

I have updated all the information inside the chainparams.cpp (public keys, magic bytes, spork keys, genesis, merkle, everything) and successfully recompiled to update and reflect the changes I have made

however when I attempt to run either the daemon or qt mainnet or -testnet it fails to properly open and instead aborts and dumps the core, however when I leave the original details in, it opens perfectly fine.

**What do I need to do after changing the merkle and genesis in the src to successfully run the QT GUI or daemon without crashing?**

[image]
[image]

**(also, when I run the ./stonecoin-qt -testnet , it shows the main net genesis hash, rather than the testnet genesis hash, which is different)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have all of the checkpoint blocks that are referenced within the source for the coin you are cloning commented out or removed?

I had a similar problem my first go at cloning a coin with it's own blockchain.

Also, what did you use to generate your genesis hash? What software/parameters.

I can recommend a piece of software if the problem lies within the parameters that make up your genesis block.

Also, the Assert error your receiving is due to the genesis hash for your testnet parameters not being valid for the rest of the genesis hash input values. I would double check under testnet in chainparams.cpp and make sure that ALL the values (nonce, timestamp, pzTimestamp, genesis reward, bits) are correct for the given genesis hash.

Comment: Can you please recommend which software you used for generating the genesis block

Comment: What hashing algorithm are you using? Also, can you provide a snippet from your main.cpp or chainparams.cpp, because depending on how it is structured you may be able to write in a chunk of code that can find the hash for you.